# Unknown reason why app throws an error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-manifest

I have an app that before worked fine but recently won't run.

Before it only had offline features, the most complex would be the local notification - but I need to add a GCM functionality to it. I searched for answers but it's so difficult to understand.

I tried to copy the code of a tutorial I've seen. I learned that I need a thing called `GCMRegistrar` but I don't know where to get it. Then I tested my app, there were errors of course because I don't have the `gcmregistrar`.

What I did is I enclosed the code in a comment block and ran the app again. That's when my app won't run anymore. After a few days of this mishap, I decided to create another app where I would put all the offline feature of my app. after that copying and pasting, I tried to run my the new app but it also won't run.

I've searched for ways to fix it and found a few fixes. Those fix works for other apps but won't work for my new app.

Here's my `MainActivity.java`, this one has the local notification

```
package com.example.mypower_build101;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button addDevice, showDevice, showDialog;
    String[] arrContentTxt;
    final Context ctx = this;
    int notifCount;
    int x = 0;
    Handler notifLauncher, notifStopper;
    String contentTxt;
    Resources res = getResources();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addDevice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddDevice);
        showDevice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShowDevice);
        showDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShowDialog);

        arrContentTxt = res.getStringArray(R.array.notifContentText);
        //contentTxt = arrContentTxt[1];
        showDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*DialogFragment diag = new SwitchCheckChange();
                diag.show(getFragmentManager(), "cbo Click");*/
                showNotif();
            }

        });
        useNotifLauncher();
        useNotifStopper();
    }
    public void useNotifLauncher(){
        notifLauncher = new Handler();
        notifLauncher.postDelayed(runNotif, 50000);
    }

    public Runnable runNotif = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            showNotif();
            notifLauncher.postDelayed(runNotif, 50000);
        }

    };

    public void useNotifStopper(){
        notifStopper = new Handler();
        notifStopper.postDelayed(stopNotif, 40000);
    }
    public Runnable stopNotif = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            cancelNotification(x);
            notifStopper.postDelayed(stopNotif, 40000);
        }

    };
    public void addClick(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AddDeviceForm.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    public void showClick(View v){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ListViewForm.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void showNotif(){
        Uri notifSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotifReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, i, 0);

        //String[] notifTitle = R.array.notifTitle;
        Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("MyPower Reminder")
            .setContentText("Unplug unused appliances and chargers")
            //.setContentText(contentTxt)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setSound(notifSound)

            .addAction(0, "View Full Reminder", pi)
            .build();

        NotificationManager notifMgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifMgr.notify(0, notif);
    }

    public void cancelNotification(int notificationId){

        if (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE!=null) {
            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ns);
            nMgr.cancel(notificationId);
        }
    }
}
```

here's my androidmanifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mypower_build101"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AddDeviceForm"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_device_form" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ListViewForm"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list_view_form" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NotifReceiver"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notif_receiver" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm not putting everything here because it would be to lengthy and I think the problems might be at the `MainActivity` or the android manifest.

If you could teach me how use the gcm thing that would be very, very, much appreciated.

Comment: Yes please post your logcat output, the stacktrace of the exception is important. Then we can say which part of your code you have to post. Working with GCM is explained by google very well here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: post some logcat bro

Comment: yet another premature context usage ... you are calling `getResources()` at wrong place ...

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys for some reason my post have an error so please use and look at this document. here's the document link

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tc2j2a2pan53r96/Ricky%20Manalo%20LogCat%20Log.docx?dl=0